# Volume of a parallelpiped from its sides and diagonals?

Tags: geometry, volume, area

If a parallelogram has sides of length $a$ and $b$, and diagonals of length $d$ and $e$, then we can find its area in the following way.  By the [polarization identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity), we have $a b \cos\theta = \frac{1}{4}|d^2-e^2|$.  Now the area is $a b \sin \theta$, which is equal to $\sqrt{a^2 b^2 - (a b \cos \theta)^2}$, or
$$\sqrt{a^2 b^2 - \frac{1}{16}(d^2-e^2)^2}.$$
This is not an exceptionally pretty formula, but maybe it's the best one can do.

How can such a formula be generalized to higher dimensions?  In particular, what is the volume of a parallelpiped, given its edge and diagonal lengths?

Comment: I think then your title should be "Area of a parallelpiped from its sides and diagonals?"

Comment: I just saw an answer that was just deleted that said to vectorize the sides of the parallelogram/paralellepid,etc and to find the determinant of the matrix formed by these vectors. I don't see what's wrong with that and am wondering why that answer was deleted

Comment: @Sawarnik, thanks, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the parallelepiped with a vertex $O$ at the origin have vertices $A$, $B$, $C$. Write $D = B+C$; $E= C+A$; $F=A+B$; and $G=A+B+C$. Further, assign these names to the lengths of edges and diagonals:
$$a := |OA|\quad b := |OB| \quad c := |OC| \quad d := |AD| \quad e := |BE| \quad f := |CF| \quad g := |OG|$$

Note that a parallelepiped (and it properties) is completely determined by *six* quantities: the lengths of three edges meeting at a vertex, and the measures of the three angles between those edges. The total number of edge-lengths and diagonal-lengths is *seven*, so there's a dependency among these values, namely
$$4 \;(\; a^2 + b^2 + c^2\;) = d^2 + e^2 + f^2 + g^2$$
Although one diagonal (say, $g$) is unnecessary, it helps to simplify the volume formula a bit:

$$\begin{align}
32 V^2 &= 32 a^2 b^2 c^2 + d^2 e^2 f^2 + g^2 ( d^2 e^2 + e^2 f^2 + f^2 d^2 )\\
&-  2 g^2 ( a^2 d^2 + b^2 e^2 + c^2 f^2 ) -  2 ( a^2 e^2 f^2 + d^2 b^2 f^2 + d^2 e^2 c^2 ) 
\end{align}$$
In the case of a *rectangular* parallelepiped, for which $d^2=e^2=f^2=g^2=a^2+b^2+c^2$, the formula reduces to $V = a b c$, as expected.

---

I derived the formulas using coordinates
$$A = (a_x,0,0) \qquad B = (b_x, b_y, 0) \qquad C = (c_x, c_y, c_z)$$
Expressing the various distances in terms of these
$$a^2 = A\cdot A = a_x^2 \qquad b^2 = B\cdot B = b_x^2 + b_y^2 \qquad c^2 = C\cdot C = c_x^2 + c_y^2 + c_z^2$$
$$d^2 = \overrightarrow{AD}\cdot \overrightarrow{AD}=\dots \quad e^2 = \overrightarrow{BE}\cdot \overrightarrow{BE} =\dots \quad f^2 = \overrightarrow{CF}\cdot \overrightarrow{CF}=\dots$$
along with
$$V = a_x b_y c_z$$
I systematically eliminated $a_x$, $b_x$, $b_y$, $c_x$, $c_y$, $c_z$ from the system with the help of Mathematica's `Resultant[]` function. (Appropriate applications of the Law of Cosines should work just as well, but the Resultant process lets me crank through the equations without having to think too hard. :)

---

An $n$-dimensional [*parallelotope*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelepiped#Parallelotope) is determined by $\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$ values. (These are the [triangular numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular%5fnumber). You can see their relevance by noting the coordinatization done above considers vectors using $1$, $2$, $3$, ..., $n$ non-zero coordinates.) The figure has *n* characteristic edge-lengths and $2^{n-1}$ diagonals, so expressing volume in terms of these is certainly *possible*. With an increasing number of "extra" lengths, the resulting formula can take a variety of forms.

Comment: Very nice!  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Let the  parallelpiped be defined by the vectors **a**, **b**, **c**.

Assume that its height is h wrt the base formed by **a**, **b** with θ as the angle between **a** and **b**. We further let **n** be unit normal vector wrt the base plane.

Notation:- * = common product (multiplication); x = cross product; . = scalar product

(**a** x **b**) . **c**

= (a * b * sin θ  **n**) . **c**

= (a*b*sin θ)* (**n** . **c**)

= (a*b*sin θ)* h

= volume of the parallelpiped

Comment: None of these answers are in terms of the edge and diagonal *lengths*.  I'm not supposing we know the edges as vectors.

Comment: Your statement "area is $absinθ$, which is equal to $√(a^2b^2−(abcosθ)^2)$" requires 2 sides and the included angle (i.e. no diagonal is involved. Mine, for 3D, has a, b, c as a representation of sides. Using vectors to handle a 3D problem is a common practice.

Comment: I used the angle (or, equivalently, vectors) in *deriving* the formula, but the end result no longer involves an angle (or vectors)  That's the point.